# How to change edit text value onReume method of an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, location, onresume

I have an app in which I am getting an address string from one activity and sending it to another activity. I want to set To and From location of the user so I have two edit text views. When the user selects location on the other activity it should be seen in edit text view of To and From. I have completed till getting the value To location in edit text view for that I have added OnResume method of an activity and have set text in edit text view. But when I return to my activity both To and From edit text view gets the same location. It should get another location in To edit text when the user will next choose To location.

Whats going wrong  here??

This is what I am getting now :
[image]

ChooseFromMapActivity

```
public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
    private LatLng center;
    private LinearLayout markerLayout;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private TextView Address;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private LatLng curentpoint;
    private LinearLayout useLocation;
    Intent intent;
    double x, y;
    StringBuilder str;
    String add;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
        Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
        markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
        useLocation = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearUseLoc);

        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
            // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

            /*
             * Set the update interval
             */
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
            mUpdatesRequested = false;

            /*
             * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
             * callbacks.
             */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        useLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,GoSend.class);
                intent.putExtra("address",add);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }


    private void stupMap() {
        try {

            mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            gps = new GPSTracker(this);

            gps.canGetLocation();

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            // Clears all the existing markers
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {
                        new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stupMap();

    }

    private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // boolean duplicateResponse;


        public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {

                    if ((addresses != null) && (addresses.size() > 0)) {
                        Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                        String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                        String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                        String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                        String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                        str.append(localityString + "");
                        str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                        str.append(zipcode + "");



                    }
                } else {
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
                add=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

GoSend

```
public class GoSend extends AppCompatActivity {
    LatLng latLng;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    LinearLayout ll;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    EditText editTextLocation;
    EditText edtxt_from;
    EditText edtxt_to;
    String stringAddress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gosendlayout);

        setUI();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        }

        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void setUI() {

        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutGoSend);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("GO-SEND");



        try {
            if (mMap == null) {
                mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                        findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         edtxt_from=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_from);
         edtxt_to=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_to);


        edtxt_from.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PickLocationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        edtxt_to.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent  i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PickLocationActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null)
            stringAddress  = bundle.getString("address");
        edtxt_from.setText(stringAddress);
        edtxt_to.setText(stringAddress);

    }
}
```

Can anyone help please...Thank you....

Comment: You are setting both To and From EditTexts with the same text. What is the problem?

Comment: Yes I know but I am unable to get what to do to get the location in To edit text view??? – @longwalker

Comment: when should i call  edtxt_to.setText(stringAddress);???

Comment: First find out and show us where you get the location. I assume from GetLocationAsync, but I didn't see that it is actually being used. Then maybe we can help you.

Comment: Location I am getting at add=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";  OnPostExecute method of ChooseFromMapActivity..I have assumed to create one activity for both To and From Location. Do I need to call 2 different activities for both??@longwalker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the same address value in `onResume()` of your `GoSend` Activity.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null)
        stringAddress = bundle.getString("address");
    edtxt_from.setText(stringAddress);
    edtxt_to.setText(stringAddress);
}
```

May be you should remove `edtxt_to.setText(stringAddress);`

Comment: Yes I know but I am unable to get what to do to get the location in To edit text view???

Comment: Where are you getting the "To" address from? In `ChooseFromMapActivity`?

Comment: I have assumed to make single activity for both To and From Location. Do I need to call 2 different activities for both??@Suhas

Comment: The address I am getting at add=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " "; OnPosExecute method of ChooseFromMapActivity.

Comment: How are the "To" and "From" addresses selected? I think you are getting the "From" address using current location. Are you selecting the "To" address from google maps? If so, you need to store that address as well in a `String` and pass it to `GoSend` activity from the intent.

Comment: Ok so do I need to make another string like add?? and call it in GoSend activity?? @Suhas

Comment: Yes, that should hopefully some the issue.

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference wnen I am calling     stringAddressTo = bundle.getString("addressTo"); @Suhas

Comment: I have created another variable and sent the string in another activity.

Comment: You need to pass the string along with `intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,GoSend.class);
intent.putExtra("address",add);
intent.putExtra("addressTo",addTo);
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: yes ofcourse this is my code : 
                intent = new Intent(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,GoSend.class);
                intent.putExtra("addressFrom",addFrom);
                intent.putExtra("addressTo",addTo);

                startActivity(intent);

Comment: I think your `addTo` String is null. Try initialising the variable and you should be able to get data in `GoSend` Activity.

Comment: addFrom=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                    + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";
                addTo=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ";                                 This is what I have done